# Can we insure the for loop iteration order when we loop over a list by "for item in list:"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, enumerator

```
for a in mylist:
     print(a)
```

I am wondering whether the item in the for loop iteration will always print the item in order?

I know "for i in (len(mylist))" can ensure the order but not sure about whether "for a in mylist" can ensure the order.

I tried on my computer it seems like it prints out the items in order. But not sure whether it is true everywhere

Thanks

Comment: It does. Lists are ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - yes. To quote [Python's wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) (bolding added for emphasis):

> The Python `for` statement **iterates over the members of a sequence in order**, executing the block each time.

Comment: I see. So the only reason when we try more effort to type  "for i in (len(mylist))" is when we have to get the exact index to do something else right?

Comment: @overloading pretty much, yes

Comment: Standard would be to use `for index, element in enumerate(mylist):`.